# Thermodynamics and enthalapy

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

In my chemistry book it says that

> To quantify the heat flow into or out of system in a constant pressure process we use a property called enthalpy

But they haven't mentioned constant volume. As in thermodynamic law it says that

$$\Delta U = Q- p \Delta V$$

If they haven't mentioned the volume being constant how can we make sure that change in energy is only change in heat?

Comment: It would help if you would give more context from your book.  Selecting only one sentence doesn't give people much to go on.

Answer (score 1):

A chemist or chemical engineer is better qualified to provide an answer.  But as I understand it chemists tend to run their reactions in vessels open to the atmosphere allowing gases to escape to the atmosphere. Therefore, volume is not held constant, but the pressure is basically constant at 1 atmosphere.

For this reason enthalpy is used instead of internal energy where enthalpy is defined as

$H=U+PV$

And enthalpy change at constant pressure is

$\Delta H=\Delta U+P\Delta V$

Combining this with

$\Delta U=Q-P\Delta V$

Gives us

$\Delta H=Q-P\Delta V +P\Delta V=Q$

Where in this case $Q$ is the heat released or absorbed at constant pressure. At constant pressure the change in enthalpy is called the "heat of reaction", which, as I understand it, can be experimentally determined using a reaction calorimeter, or calculated using the standard heat of formation of all the reactants.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Shame on the author of your chemistry book for introducing enthalpy in this way.  No wonder you are confused.

Here is the correct definition of enthalpy, and an example of how it is applied:  Enthalpy H is a convenient thermodynamic property of a substance at thermodynamic equilibrium that is defined by $$H=U+PV$$where U is the internal energy, P is the pressure, and V is the volume of the substance.  H comes into play in many types of problems we encounter in thermodynamics, but is not any more fundamental than U.

An example of how enthalpy comes into play is in the constant pressure expansion of an ideal gas.  From the first law, for this situation, we know that $$\Delta U=Q-P\Delta V$$Rewriting this in a slightly different way, we obtain:  $$\Delta U+P\Delta V=\Delta H=Q$$Therefore, for a constant pressure expansion of an ideal gas (or any other gas for that matter), we know that the amount of heat we have to add is equal to the change in enthalpy.  And, if we know the enthalpy of the gas in the initial and final states, we can predict the amount of heat required.

Comment: Like I said, a chemical engineer can answer better! 